# Filter specific triples from graph using SPARQL

Tags: filter, sparql

I am writing a sparql to fetch triples from two graphs. Below is my query:

```
select ?sub ?hicl ?fdpl

where  {
  graph     
<http://ontology.com/ABC_01> { 
  ?subs a abc:DrugSubstance .
  ?subs <http://www.geneontology.org/formats/oboInOwl#xref> ?hicl_crossref .
  FILTER regex(str(?hicl_crossref), "hiclseqno") .}
 
   graph    
 <http://ontology.com/ABBANK_01> { 
   
   ?hicl umls:hasSTY fdbank:hiclseqno .
   ?hicl skos:prefLabel ?fdpl .
   
   BIND(xsd:integer(REPLACE(?hicl , '.*/', '' )) AS ?hicl_id )
   MINUS {?hicl_crossref ?p ?zz}
   
   }
    }
  
limit 1
```

I would like to filter out those triples where ?hicl_crossref already exist in ABC_01 graph. variable ?sub shoud be null as it is not mapped to ?hicl.  How can I achieve this?

Comment: I don't get it I think. How are both graphs connected? Can you share sample data please, and also the expected result.